# Tracking clicks on a specific Select2 drop down item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I'm working on an A/B test and for the changed variation, I want to track the clicks on a `Select2` drop down option.

This particular option is added dynamically which I think is complicating things (I'm also changing the dropdowns placeholder but I don't think that's messing anything up).

With my AB/ testing platform, I can only really track **clicks for a specific selector**, so I'm trying to figure out any way I can have the selection of this option register.

Unfortunately I can't change any of the markup itself, but I can use `JavaScript/JQ`.

Normally if I was scripting I'd just retrieve the selected item from the `Select2`, but in this case I'm constrained to using an actual selector where clicks can be tracked.

I'm using event listeners to simulate and test CSS selectors (bottom of JS code) but with no luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').select2({
     placeholder: "Old Placeholder",
      minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    });

     var newOption = {
        id: "01",
        text: 'Dynamically Added Option',
        value: "01"
     };
    
    var newOption = new Option(newOption.text, newOption.id, false, false);
    $('#dropdown').append(newOption);
    
    
   $('#dropdown').trigger('change.select2');
   
   $('.select2-selection__placeholder').html('New Placeholder'); 
   
   /******* HERE'S WHERE I'M TESTING SELECTORS FOR WHEN "DYNAMICALLY ADDED OPTION" IS SELECTED *******/
   
   // track select2 list item with an id containing the new option's id
   $('.select2-results__option[id*="01"]').on('click', function(){
     alert("this never happens");
   });
   
   $('option[value="01"]').on('click', function(){
     alert("this also never happens");
   });
   
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="dropdown">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you're just trying to add an event listener to whatever is the second child element in the dropdown list?

Comment: Not exactly... I need to supply a CSS selector for the testing platform to measure clicks on, and the selector must target the item that I dynamically added to the select2. I was using event listeners to simulate that, to see if I could get a click event to register for the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a change event for the select with a small test for the new element like:

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '01') {
      console.log('The new option selected');
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropdown').select2({
    placeholder: "Old Placeholder",
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
  });

  var newOption = {
    id: "01",
    text: 'Dynamically Added Option',
    value: "01"
  };

  var newOption = new Option(newOption.text, newOption.id, false, false);

  $('#dropdown').append(newOption);
  $('#dropdown').trigger('change.select2');
  $('.select2-selection__placeholder').html('New Placeholder');


  // track select2 list item with an id containing the new option's id
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '01') {
      console.log('The new option selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="dropdown">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```